# Solving an inequality fot hyperbolas

Tags: geometric-inequalities

I am trying to solve:
$$\frac{1}{x-2} < \frac{1}{x+2}. $$ 
I think I have done so by sketching the graph, 
namely $-2 < x < 2 $ but I would like to see how I could have done this algebraically.

TIA

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac1{x-2}<\dfrac1{x+2}\iff\dfrac{x+2-(x-2)}{(x-2)(x+2)}<0$$

So we need $(x-2)(x+2)<0\iff -2<x<2$

Comment: So easy! I was trying to make it more difficult than it was.
Thank you